# Add TTL programatically firestore

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

To define an index in firestore you can use, `firestore.indexes.json`. Is there a way to define TTL properties in a similar way, so those are automatically deployed when switching environment (dev, staging, prod) ?

Answer (score 1):

The Firebase CLI doesn't support this, or at least not in a documented way.  File a [feature request on the firebase-tools GitHub](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools) to make your needs known for that.

You can [use gcloud to set ttl policies](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/ttl#create_ttl_policy) programmatically instead.

Comment: FYI it's possible (but undocumented), see my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Although not documented it seems like it is possible to define TTL policies like this:

```
  "fieldOverrides": [
    {
      "collectionGroup": "fcm_tokens",
      "fieldPath": "expiresAt",
      "ttl": true,
      "indexes": []
    }
  ]
```

in firestore.indexes.json

[Here is a PR](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/pull/6647/files) adding the documentation in the repository readme